# Filtering mysql query results by column priority

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter out rows from joined select query results that have the same 'id_user' column value but are of lower sorting priority.
Column 'sort1' has the highest priority and 'sort4' has the lowest priority.The name of the column is what sets the priority not the value inside.

Table users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;



INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Some Name'),
(2, 'Some Other Name');


ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);
```

Table items:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `items` (`id_user`, `sort1`, `sort2`, `sort3`, `sort4`) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL, 39, NULL),
(2, NULL, NULL, NULL, 45),
(1, NULL, 34, NULL, NULL);
```

I tried the following query and get more results than i needed:

```
SELECT
    users.name,
    items.id_user,
    items.sort1,
    items.sort2,
    items.sort3,
    items.sort4
FROM
    items
LEFT JOIN users ON items.id_user = users.user_id
WHERE
    (
        items.sort1 = '' OR items.sort1 IS NULL
    ) AND(
        items.sort2 = 34 OR items.sort2 IS NULL
    ) AND(
        items.sort3 = 39 OR items.sort3 IS NULL
    ) AND(
        items.sort4 = 45 OR items.sort4 IS NULL
    )
```

Actual result:

```
|       Name      | id_user | sort1 | sort2 | sort3 | sort4 |
+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------|
|  Some Name      |    1    |  NULL |  NULL |   39  |  NULL |
| Some Other Name |    2    |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |   45  |
|  Some Name      |    1    |  NULL |   34  |  NULL |  NULL |
```

The first row is extra result because the third row has higher priority(sort2).

Expected result:

```
|       Name      | id_user | sort1 | sort2 | sort3 | sort4 |
+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------|
|  Some Name      |    1    |  NULL |   34  |  NULL |  NULL |
| Some Other Name |    2    |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |   45  |
```

I also tried GROUP BY id_user and ORDER BY priority columns but i didn't get the expected result

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you have to question whether your schema design is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your `items` table, added the `id` field

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `items` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `id_user`, `sort1`, `sort2`, `sort3`, `sort4`) VALUES
(1, 1, NULL, NULL, 39, NULL),
(2, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, 45),
(3, 1, NULL, 34, NULL, NULL);
```

So you can try request like this, I changed `FROM` clause from `items` to `users`

```
SELECT
  users.name,
  items.id,
  items.id_user,
  items.sort1,
  items.sort2,
  items.sort3,
  items.sort4
FROM
  users
LEFT JOIN 
  items ON items.id = (
    SELECT i.id FROM items AS i WHERE i.id_user = users.user_id ORDER BY -i.sort1 DESC, -i.sort2 DESC, -i.sort3 DESC, -i.sort4 DESC LIMIT 1
  )
ORDER BY -items.sort1 DESC, -items.sort2 DESC, -items.sort3 DESC, -items.sort4 DESC
```

Result

```
|            name | id | id_user |  sort1 |  sort2 |  sort3 |  sort4 |
|-----------------|----|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|       Some Name |  3 |       1 | (null) |     34 | (null) | (null) |
| Some Other Name |  2 |       2 | (null) | (null) | (null) |     45 |
```